# Sort array of objects based on two fields - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have some data and I would like to sort the array based on two different fields and change the "order" property as well. Each object has a position property with a value of "Before" and "After". Before should come first followed by After. Plus, the before property objects within a catgory should have a separate index and the after property object within a category should have a separate index starting at 1. I am almost done but not able to fix the order. Please help.

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 0,
    "mdmStep": {
      "name": "Insert to Stage",
      "id": 1
    },
    "relativePosition": {
      "name": "After",
      "id": 2
    },
    "order": 1,
    "details": [{
      "commandText": "SELECT * FROM MDSRC_PRO_KOMODO_TRAN"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "mdmStep": {
      "name": "Insert to Stage",
      "id": 1
    },
    "relativePosition": {
      "name": "Before",
      "id": 1
    },
    "order": 4,
    "details": [{
      "commandText": "SELECT * FROM MDSRC_PRO_KOMODO_CONFIG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "mdmStep": {
      "name": "Insert to Stage",
      "id": 1
    },
    "relativePosition": {
      "name": "After",
      "id": 2
    },
    "order": 2,
    "details": [{
      "commandText": "SELECT * FROM MDSRC_PRO_KOMODO_ADDR"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "mdmStep": {
      "name": "Insert to Raw",
      "id": 2
    },
    "relativePosition": {
      "name": "After",
      "id": 2
    },
    "order": 3,
    "details": [{
      "commandText": "SELECT * FROM MDSRC_PRO_KOMODO_ADDR"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "mdmStep": {
      "name": "Insert to Raw",
      "id": 2
    },
    "relativePosition": {
      "name": "After",
      "id": 2
    },
    "order": 5,
    "details": [{
      "commandText": "SELECT * FROM MDSRC_PRO_KOMODO_CONFIG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "mdmStep": {
      "name": "Update Match Fields",
      "id": 5
    },
    "relativePosition": {
      "name": "Before",
      "id": 1
    },
    "order": 6,
    "details": [{
      "commandText": "HELLO ARUN"
    }]
  }
]



const groups = _.groupBy(data, 'mdmStep.name')

const groupValues = _.reduce(_.keys(groups), (a, c) => {
  a[c] = _.orderBy(groups[c], 'relativePosition.id').map((i, idx) => {
    if (i.relativePosition.id === 1) {
      return {
        ...i,
        order: idx

      }
    }
    return {
      ...i,
      order: idx

    }
  });
  return a
}, {})

const changeOrders = _.orderBy(_.flattenDeep((_.map(_.keys(groupValues), group => {
  return _.map(groupValues[group], (i, index) => {
    return {
      ...i,
      order: index || index + 1
    }
  })

}))), 'mdmStep.id')

console.log(changeOrders)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The expected output is

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "mdmStep": {
            "name": "Insert to Stage",
            "id": 1
        },
        "relativePosition": {
            "name": "Before",
            "id": 1
        },
        "order": 1,
        "details": [
            {
                "commandText": "SELECT * FROM MDSRC_PRO_KOMODO_CONFIG"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "mdmStep": {
            "name": "Insert to Stage",
            "id": 1
        },
        "relativePosition": {
            "name": "After",
            "id": 2
        },
        "order": 1,
        "details": [
            {
                "commandText": "SELECT * FROM MDSRC_PRO_KOMODO_TRAN"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "mdmStep": {
            "name": "Insert to Stage",
            "id": 1
        },
        "relativePosition": {
            "name": "After",
            "id": 2
        },
        "order": 2,
        "details": [
            {
                "commandText": "SELECT * FROM MDSRC_PRO_KOMODO_ADDR"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "mdmStep": {
            "name": "Insert to Raw",
            "id": 2
        },
        "relativePosition": {
            "name": "After",
            "id": 2
        },
        "order": 1,
        "details": [
            {
                "commandText": "SELECT * FROM MDSRC_PRO_KOMODO_ADDR"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "mdmStep": {
            "name": "Insert to Raw",
            "id": 2
        },
        "relativePosition": {
            "name": "After",
            "id": 2
        },
        "order": 2,
        "details": [
            {
                "commandText": "SELECT * FROM MDSRC_PRO_KOMODO_CONFIG"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "mdmStep": {
            "name": "Update Match Fields",
            "id": 5
        },
        "relativePosition": {
            "name": "Before",
            "id": 1
        },
        "order": 1,
        "details": [
            {
                "commandText": "HELLO ARUN"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the above response, before is followed by after, and index gets reset to 1 again for after. This is the expected behavior.

Please advice.

Comment: @nina-scholz Could you help me out with this please?

Answer (score 0):

In `changeOrders` you increase `index + 1` at each iteration, but must do in only if `index === 0`, just write like this `return {...i, order: index || index + 1}`

Comment: I checked it with actual data, and there seems to be a minor bug. In the below code, check indexes 3 and 4, order should be increased in index 4 - https://jsfiddle.net/k6pf90dg/